# Using localstorage in React apps instead of useContext

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, use-context

I'm learning react and I'm trying to create a cart for an e-commerce app.

In my tutorial, we are creating the cart using useContext (because we will need it in several places in our application).
However, when I was learning JavaScript vanilla, I created another e-commerce app and I used the localStorage for my cart.

So my question: Is it a bad practice to use localStorage instead of useContext in React? Which is better? In which cases?

Comment: Both have very different purposes.```useContext``` is just a hook to create some common data so that every hierarchical component have access to that data without passing it individually to each component through props. While ```local Sorage``` serves you differently by storing the data in the browser itself so that the data still remains in the web even after the browser is closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Context` can be reactive on changes, so you can update its value and see the change in all components subscribed, however with localStorage yo can't directly.

Think about your feature, do you need persist the data when user close the navigator? use `localStorage`

or do you need handle data dynamically through different components? then use `Context`

PD: Also, you can use both, `localStorage` would be used on mount and unmount events, and `Context` would be used in the rest of life cycle app.

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` is persistent. The data will be available after you refresh your browser. It is saved locally in browser.

`context` is not persistent. The data will be gone after you refresh.

Which is better? They are two different tools. Maybe can use both, every time you visit the web, check if there is something in `localStorage`, then add it to `context`.