# Any problem using localStorage instead of $page.params.id in Sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

In sveltekit, any problem using localStorage for passing along a post id from a list to a detail or edit page instead of using $page.params.id?

Instead of having a page "edit/[id].svelte" it will just be "edit.svelte".

Should be easy to understand without showing any code. I know it has been somewhat answered e g for react and perhaps the answer is the same but I only know svelte. Similar to this question: [Using localstorage in React apps instead of useContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70669242/using-localstorage-in-react-apps-instead-of-usecontext)

Pros and cons? Any risk of it being slow to setItem before getItem in edit.svelte compared to using $page.params.id?

One advantage is VS Code, having a more practical and clear file structure. The thing that started me thinking about this. Instead of a directory with edit/[id].svelte it would just be edit.svelte.

Answer (score 3):

Those are two very different things, if you have `edit/[id].svelte` you can have server side rendering, while if you rely on localStorage you can not do that at all.

I see no benefits to doing this *at all*, even think you are making your code unnecessary complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Only in client of course. Perhaps cleaner and less complicated actually with no need for import? Easier?

Comment: @PålBergström: This site aims to collect quality questions and their answers, and has been successful while other sites (e.g., Yahoo Answers) have failed because it asks for and encourages active curation by site members. It has nothing to do with kindness and all to do with how the site is supposed to work. And I wish that you have a nice Sunday as well.